# my headlines are pink and the table of contest is red

Tags: color, text

I have used a template where the headlines appear pink and the table of contest appear red. I just want all text in the report to be black. How do I do this?

Comment: The template defines links to be coloured. Templates give you a predefined look additional to the default stuff LaTe provides for scientiic writing.

Comment: Without knowing which template you use, this question cannot be answered. Using `\hypersetup{hidelinks}` is my best guess.

Comment: Welcome, Lina. The appearance of a documents depends on a multitude of settings, and without knowing which ones you use it is hard to give advice. If you can't sort out the problem yourself, please post a small complete document (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}) that shows the problem. Just add it to your post using the edit button at the bottom left.

Comment: Can you add a link to the template you use?